# Replace include directive with a different file name using make

Tags: c, makefile

I have a header file, `sample_A.h`, which has an include statement of the form `#include "sample_B.h"`. I also have another header file `sample_C.h`. I would like header file `sample_A.h` to include `sample_C.h` instead of `sample_B.h`, but under no circumstances can I edit anything outside of the Makefile used to build the project. What would be the best way to "redirect" `sample_A.h` to include `sample_C.h` instead of `sample_B.h` by solely editing the Makefile? Assume that both `sample_C.h` and `sample_B.h` will allow `sample_A.h` to compile.

EDIT: I am working on a project which has a vast build structure. Some files are outdated, but due to upper management orders, these files should not be messed with until future meetings take place. In the meantime, I am trying to figure out a way to circumvent these outdated files (and their outdated include directives) without touching the files themselves. I am using the gcc compiler.

Comment: Rename "sample_C.h" -> "sample_B.h" wouldn't happen to be an option?

Comment: rename `sample_C.h` to `sample_B.h` ?

Comment: Would it be allowed to move "Sample_B.h" out of the way? I.e. copy it somewhere safe and delete it from where compiler sees it temporarily, i.e. move it back afterwards?

Comment: Show your current makefile please.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe there's a better approach than what you're trying.

Comment: What compiler are you using, did you study the documentation on the topic of include path, include order etc.?

Comment: Can you copy everything to a copy of the project, then rename C->B there (not touching originals) do the building there and copy the result back? Risky and a maintenance hell, admittedly.

Comment: Are you allowed to create new files? If so, then John Bollinger's solution is a good one. (I'd use symbolic links rather than copying files.) If not, then there is another solution, but it's pretty twisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like header file `sample_A.h` to include `sample_C.h` instead of `sample_B.h`, but under no circumstances can I edit anything outside of the Makefile used to build the project.

In principle, the compiler is at leisure to choose how to interpret the file identifier presented in an `#include` directive (*i.e.* `"sample_B.h"`), but in practice, every compiler you're likely ever to meet interprets it as a file name or path.  Thus, if you have a file whose (only) simple name is `sample_C.h`, and you have no allowable way to provide another name for it (by copying it or creating a symlink to it, for example) then it is unlikely that there is any way that file will ever be chosen to satisfy an `#include "sample_B.h"` directive.

If, however, the two headers have the same simple name but reside in different directories, e.g. `src/sample_B.h` and `custom/sample_B.h`, then it is normally possible to influence which is selected via compiler options that affect the search path for include files.  The traditional option of that kind for Unix C compilers is `-I`.